# Click is not working during ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have two divs in one div i have 3 tabs on the top..

Tab A, Tab B and Tab C like this ..

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 live_contets" style='padding-right:13px !important;'>
    <table class="table live_c" style="border:3px solid #0d8aee !important;margin-bottom:0px !important;border-radius:16px !important;">
        <tr>
            <td class="live_tab tab_actions1" style="text-align:center;border:0px solid #0d8aee !important;" id="lll1" data="match_row">
                <a data="match_row" class="match_row1 tab_actions">
                <p style="margin:4px !important;">Tab A</p></a>
            </td>
            <td class="nlive_tab tab_actions1" style="text-align:center;border:0px solid #0d8aee !important;border-left:3px solid #0d8aee !important;border-right:3px solid #0d8aee !important;" id="lll2" data="points">
                <a data="points" class="points tab_actions"><p style="margin:4px !important;">Tab B</p></a>
            </td>
            <td class="nlive_tab tab_actions1" style="text-align:center;border:0px solid #0d8aee !important;border-right:0px solid #0d8aee !important;" id="lll3" data="owners">
                <a data="owners" class="owners tab_actions"><p style="margin:4px !important;">Tab C</p></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="match_row"></div>
```

And in second DIV i have content which continuously updated every 3 seconds the by `set Interval` function of `query`..

In that Ajax call i get HTML which overwrites on second div..
`second div is match_row..`
The code is like this..

```
setInterval(function()
{
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['add']))
        {
    ?>
        var add = <?php echo $_GET['add'] ?>;
        var url = '<?php echo url("?well='+add+'"); ?>';       
    <?php
        }
        else
        {
    ?>
            var add = 0;
            var url = '<?php echo url("?well='+add+'"); ?>';  
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:url,
      async:false,
      cache: false,
      datatype:"html",
      success:function(data)
      {
          $("#match_row").html("");
          $("#match_row").html(data);
      }
    });
}, 3000);
```

now problem is that if i **click** on any of tabs **during Ajax call** it doesn't fire..
my onclick code is like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent,
    event = (ua.match(/iPad/i) || ua.match(/iPhone/)) ? "touchstart" : "click";
    jQuery("body").on(event, '.tab_actions1', function(e) {
        var datas = $(this).attr("data");
        console.log(datas);
    });
});
```

Thought content of first div is static..
Any help would be highly appreciable..

Comment: `async:false,` makes the UI to freeze. And FYI, `$("#match_row").html("");` is useless in your code becasue anyway you set just line below new HTML content

Comment: It worked Man thanks a lot @A.Wolff